# how large E-Commerce applications can be created using CMS tools?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, e-commerce, dotnetnuke

Can one create a good e-Commerce application using a tool like DNN merged with some ready made shopping cart?  I did not use DNN before, but I think, it will be tough thing to do, I think I will face troubles with performance and maintainability.

Further I think it is almost impossible to convert asp.net web application to DNN, this will wast more time even if I throughaway the UI layer.

Probably it is good to create a small e-commerce application using DNN, that kind of applications that costs 3000 USD, created for once, and not likely to extended.

Talk to me about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what your goal is.  Plenty of people operate e-commerce sites using DNN.  If by large you mean you are looking to take on Amazon then DNN is not for you.

In my opinion DNN's strength is around content management, if you need significant content management and commerce functionality then DNN is likely a good choice.  If your primary concern is commerce functionality with little or no other content management needs, then I would look to something more focused on commerce.

It is very possible to convert existing apps to DNN.  You will need some understanding of how module development and skinning in DNN works, and then you will find that much of the existing code can likely be copy paste into a module.  Once you understand how/when skins and modules are run you will find you can drop in pretty much any ASP.Net code and expect it to work.  Of course to take advantage of DNN core features (membership and permissions are common items) you will need to use the DNN APIs.  Also it is possible to run DNN side by side with an existing application under the same website.

To me it makes sense to build on DNN if your application will receive significant benefit from off the shelf core and extension module functionality.  If you can't remove significant features from your development schedule by using DNN, then you probably shouldn't use DNN.

Answer (score 3):

1. ***Can one create a good e-Commerce application using a tool like DNN merged with some ready made shopping cart?***  Yes... But you'll be better served by just using some of the off the shelf cart modules for DNN.
2. ***Further I think it is almost impossible to convert asp.net web application to DNN, this will wast more time even if I throughaway the UI layer.***  This entirely depends on your skill level in writing DNN modules and the needs of the application.  No way to even answer other than to say: Why bother?  If the application is done and ready to go, there's probably not much of a reason to rebuild it within DNN.
3. ***Probably it is good to create a small e-commerce application using DNN, that kind of applications that costs 3000 USD, created for once, and not likely to extended.***  There are numerous free and open source eCommerce modules for DNN.  There are also several good paid for eCommerce modules.  Why bother creating your own?  Especially if you don't have much experience in writing modules for DNN...

Comment: For first question, I thought using DNN will save my time, I would not create a backend from scratch.  What do u think?

Comment: @Costa: my answer wasn't clear enough.  I meant, just buy or implement an existing shopping cart *module* for DNN.  It will save time.  Of course, I have no idea what your requirements are or even if an existing solution meets them.  Do some research.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found the currently available DNN E-Commerce modules to be good enough to run a site that is really focused on E-Commerce. You should make sure NBStore (a free an Open Source Module) won't meet your E-Commerce as it is very well built but isn't particularly feature rich. Catalook, while feature rich, is terribly written, and I highly recommend avoiding it. Most the other available modules don't have all the needed features for a serious online store.

We've been using AbleCommerce when E-Commerce is the primary focus. AbleCommerce is feature rich, very well built, and relatively easy to customize and extend. We have done basic integration between AbleCommerce and DNN where we used DNN for the main site and AbleCommerce for the E-Commerce piece. AbleCommerce just ran as a Virtual Directory within the DNN site. We did not integrate login/user functionality which was fine for the site. If you truly need the capabilities of DNN, this may be a good way to go.

Comment: +1: I've used CataLook before and agree the OP should "look" elsewhere.